# Blank screen in Fedora 26 after login with Nvidia Drivers

Tags: fedora, nvidia, nouveau

After installing Nvidia drivers on my fresh Fedora 26 system, I am able to log in to my account but after that I get a blank screen before the desktop loads every time. I can confirm this is related to using Nvidia's drivers because when I disable them and use nouveau I can boot in just fine. I have tried using variations of nomodeset with no avail. I am using a GTX 760 and installed the drivers with rpm fusion (I also attempted this with drivers directly from Nvidia).

I want to use Nvidia's drivers because I am getting some odd feeling lag with nouveau and would like to see if Nvidia's stuff fixes it. Anyone able to offer some wisdom?

Edit: I cannot only log in to a console with runlevel 3.

Comment: Ask nvidia for fixing the driver.

Comment: Can you login to a text-only console with (Ctrl)+(Alt)+(F1)?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question.

Comment: Uncomment `WaylandEnable=false` in `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` and reboot the system. Nvidia binary blob and Wayland aren't friends yet.